# How to stop animation at particular state

Tags: c#, wpf, storyboard

I'm creating a fadeIn/fadeOut animation from code behind. I was trying to stop animation at a particular blink time and it is working fine. But I want to make sure that when my animation stops it should stop in fadeOut state. Below is my code:

```
public void AddAnimation(long blinkDuration = 0)
        {
            var fadeIn = new DoubleAnimation(0.3, 1, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), FillBehavior.HoldEnd)
            {
                BeginTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0)
            };

            var fadeOut = new DoubleAnimation(1.0, 0.3, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), FillBehavior.HoldEnd)
            {
                BeginTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5)
            };

            storyboard = new Storyboard();
            Storyboard.SetTarget(fadeIn, this);
            Storyboard.SetTarget(fadeOut, this);
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(fadeIn, new PropertyPath("(Opacity)"));
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(fadeOut, new PropertyPath("(Opacity)"));
            storyboard.RepeatBehavior = blinkDuration == 0
                                            ? RepeatBehavior.Forever
                                            : new RepeatBehavior(new TimeSpan(0, 0, Convert.ToInt32(blinkDuration)));
            storyboard.Children.Add(fadeIn);
            storyboard.Children.Add(fadeOut);
            storyboard.Begin();
        }
```

My question is how I will make my icon state fadeOut on Storyboard Stop after blink interval.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have fixed it. I changed my Storyboard.Begin call and registered storyboard.Completed event, on which I'm calling storyboard.Stop().

Below is my changed code:

```
storyboard.Completed += StoryboardCompleted;
storyboard.Begin(this, true);

void StoryboardCompleted(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   storyboard.Stop(this);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`FillBehaviour` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.timeline.fillbehavior%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) value of `HoldEnd` which will keep the last value (or the `To` value) that you set in your `Storyboard`. This way, you can ensure what the end value will be. The only problem that you may have using this property is that you may need to run your animation several times.

To do that, you can attach a handler to the [`Completed` Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.timeline.completed%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and re-run the `Storyboard` after it finishes if a certain condition is met (number of times run, or seconds passed, or data has arrived, etc.):

```
private void OnStoryboardCompleted(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (someConditionIsTrue) storyboard.Start();
}
```